# random nr for 000001 - 000100

Tags: c#, random

How to generate 6 dig random number (within specific interval)? would

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

still work in this case?  (e.g  rand.Next(000000, 000101)) I need to keep 6dig format

asp.net C#

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to separate the numeric value from the text representation. 000101 is the same number as 101. Pick the random number using `Next(min, max)` and then format it however you want, e.g. with `value.ToString("000000")` or `value.ToString("D6")` (whichever you find more readable).

Note that you should [take care when using `Random`](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) - there are a few subtle issues. (In particular, you very rarely want to actually create a new instance with the parameterless constructor in the line of code before you use it...)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`string.Format("{0:000000}", rand.Next(0, 100));`

Comment: Any reason for using `string.Format` with a compound format string instead of calling `ToString` on the result of `rand.Next`?

Comment: I think it explicitly expresses my intentions of actually formatting the string. Appending zeroes, it's not the "optimal solution".

Comment: @JK: Who said anything about appending zeroes? I meant `rand.Next(0, 100).ToString("000000")` which I think expresses the intentions more clearly, as the execution flow reads left to right, and it's converting the integer into a string.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I know, I think they are both alright too be honest. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JK: They're both *okay* - but I prefer the simplicity of the format string without the {0:} part, and the left-to-right execution flow. I probably wouldn't have mentioned it, but this is the second time in the last few hours where I'm seen string.Format used where IMO ToString is simpler.

Answer (score 3):

A number doesn't have a format at all, you give it a format when you convert the number to a string. So, the random part of the code is the same, you just format the number in a specific way:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
string formatted = rnd.Next(1, 101).ToString("000000");
```

Note: The lower bound for the `Next` method is inclusive and the upper bound is exclusive. `Next(0, 101)` would give you a result between 000000 and 000100.